# Проверка на четность и вывод с помощью цикла

Tags: javascript, html, css

Функция должна выводить в out-10 четные годы от 1950 до 2000 включительно
Решить с помощью цикла

если выполнить код выводит 2001

```
function t10() {
    let out = document.querySelector('.out-10');
    let a = ' ';
    for (i = 1950; i <= 2000; i++); {
        if (i%2) {
            a += i + ' ';
        }
    }
    out.innerHTML = a;
}

document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = t10;
```

Comment: прежде, чем писать ``if (i%2)``, нужно разобраться с тем, что оно делает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Результат a % b – это остаток от целочисленного деления a на b. Он может быть равен нулю, а может не равен. При делении на 2 остаток будет ноль. И нужно как раз проверять на это

```js
function t10() {
    let out = document.querySelector('.out-10');
    let a = ' ';
    for (let i = 1950; i <= 2000; i++) {    
        if (i%2 === 0) { // <!---------
            a += i + ' ';
        }
    }
    out.innerHTML = a;
}

t10();
//document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = t10;
```

```html
<div class="out-10"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо незнал что нужно создавать переменную в цикле и ставить 3 '==='

Comment: @Joker15 просто если не делать переменную - то она становится глобальной. Если в таком маленьком кусочкее кода это может быть не страшно, то в более обширном и, тем более, вне функции - это чревато.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому пригодится — другой подход:

```
function t10() {
  let a = ' ';
  let i = 1948;
  while ( i <= 2000 ) { 
    i++   
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      a += i + ' ';
    }
  }
  document.querySelector('.out-10').innerHTML = (a)
}
document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = t10;
```